# What is the output format of microphone to save it in Wav

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, audio, wav

I'm recording audio from the microphone in unity and saving it as an AudioClip. The thing is I need to know in which format (either ogg or uncompressed) it is saved so I can convert it to Wav. I would also need help to convert it to wav.

Comment: You can check first 4 bytes of your file/stream for the values `4F 67 67 53` which are [`.ogg` file signature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures). I don't know any library to use `.ogg` though.

Answer (score 1):

You may try both cases with SoX library but it's hard to put it inside unity project

Answer (score 0):

If your going to after saving your audio just convert to wav it won't matter much which one you pick. You could in theory lose some quality with the compressed version. You will want to use a program like [Audacity](http://www.audacityteam.org/) to convert it to wav.